# Not able to serve scripts from certain folders in ASP.NET project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I added MVC to an existing ASP.NET WebForms project. I am attempting to serve a JavaScript file from an alternative folder than ~/Scripts, but I keep getting 404 errors when it's not in scripts.

This configuration works:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/apps/test").Include(
    "~/Scripts/test.js"
 ));
```

This does not:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/apps/test").Include(
    "~/Features/Upload/Scripts/test.js"
));
```

```

I am running against IIS and not IIS Express. I have doublechecked that the file exists, and that the IIS_USRS user has access to the file.

I have also tried switching to IIS Express and it does not fix the issue. I created a new test project and it seems to work out of the box, so I'm wondering if I missed a step when I added MVC to the app.

Comment: Sounds like the file isn't copied during deployment. Right click on that file and check its properties. Make sure 'Build Action' is set to 'Content'. Sometimes it is set to 'None'.

Comment: The issue is happening on my local dev machine.

Comment: Even on local dev, when  you hit F5 to run/debug, it is still 'deployed'... so you still need to check that property.

Comment: Build Action was already set to Content.

Comment: The only reason I could think of is the path is wrong, but obviously you would have tripled check that. Try setting `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false` and then when you run view the source of your html... perhaps there could be a clue somewhere.